# ubuntu 14.04 coldfusion 8 cannot find files

Tags: ubuntu, coldfusion

Have new computer with Ubuntu 14.04.  Moved over all my Cold Fusion files from backup of old computer. When I try to access my reports I get

Not Found

The requested URL /reports/frag11a.cfm was not found on this server.

Same for the administrator. The program files are all there in var/www/reports, and CFIDE is in var/www.

Can someone tell me how I reconnect ColdFusion to these files?

Comment: Please update the question to include information about the webserver (if any) that is in use.  i.e. Apache, Nginx, built in.  Also, how is it configured and how many sites are set up?  This controls where CF looks for the web root.  I'll also point out that CF8 is obscenely old and there's little reason to use it on a new server, but if I recall (it's been a while) the default web root is something like {cfisntalllocation}/wwwroot/ if you're hitting CF directly using the built-in JRun server.

Comment: Hi, I am using Apache.  I installed it but did no additional configuration.  There is one site.  Re CF8, I am using a test version for development and cannot upgrade it without paying for it.  I'll do that when the development is complete, which it almost was before my old machine crashed.

Answer (score 0):

Were you running on a Windows box previously? Linux is case sensitive and is not quite as forgiving as Windows.

Comment: I was always running under linux.